# How to see the values of "configure" settings in Karate?

Tags: javascript, config, karate, configure

In Karate, you can set certain framework settings via the `configure` keyword, such as

```
* configure httpTimeout = 5000

* configure ssl = true

* eval karate.configure('readTimeout',10000);
```

But how can you see the values of these settings? Can you determine the defaults? What if you need to temporarily override them for part of a test and restore the previous value afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The `karate.configure()` method and the `configure` keyword relate back to a singleton object called ScenarioEngine. You can access this object from the `karate` object from within Javascript interop, via the `getEngine()` method, which in turn has a `getConfig()` method to access getters and setters for these values.

```
    * eval print(karate.getEngine().getConfig().getReadTimeout());
    * eval karate.configure("readTimeout",12345)
    * eval print(karate.getEngine().getConfig().getReadTimeout());
```

which will print:

```
30000
12345
```

showing the original default of 30000, and confirming the updated value of 12345. (This will work the exact same way using the `configure` keyword.)

You can use JS's Object.keys() to see all the available getter and setter methods for config values on the object returned by `.config()`.

Comment: thanks :) I honestly did not know `Object.keys()` would work. I agree that `karate.config` would be nice to have that returns a json of all values, feel free to open a feature request (and a PR if possible ;) - BTW `eval` could possibly be omitted for the above snippets